# Is there a syntax for type annotation within an expression? (example use case: Default trait)

Tags: rust

Is there a way to write type annotations directly within an expression, e.g. when using `Default::default()`?

For instance, in the following example the compiler obviously cannot infer the type:

```
use std::default::Default;

#[deriving(Default, Show)]
struct Point{ x: int, y: int };

println!("Default Point: {}", Default::default())
```

The only solution I have found is by annotating the type on the LHS of an additional `let` binding.

```
let p: Point = Default::default();
println!("Default Point: {}", p)
```

I was hoping that it is somehow possible to tell the compiler directly, which version of `Default::default()` I want. Maybe by something like this:

```
println!("Default Point: {}", Default::default() as Point)
println!("Default Point: {}", Default::default<Point>())
println!("Default Point: {}", Default<Point>::default())
println!("Default Point: {}", Point::default())
```

But none of these is valid syntax.

Comment: I wonder if [UFCS](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0132-ufcs.md) would allow this as `<Point as Default>::default()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is currently done in the standard library using helper functions like `from_str`.

The basic idea is that using a function allows you to introduce a type parameter, that you can then use, like this:

```
use std::default::Default;

#[deriving(Default, Show)]
struct Point{ x: int, y: int }

fn default<T: Default>() -> T { Default::default() }

fn main() {
    println!("Default Point: {}", default::<Point>());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**2021 Answer:**

It looks like in modern Rust, the work-around is no longer necessary. Also, the suggestion by @Shepmaster works. With a current compiler these two variants are valid:

```rust
#[derive(Default, Debug)]
struct Point{ x: i32, y: i32 }

fn main() {
    println!("Default Point: {:?}", Point::default());
    println!("Default Point: {:?}", <Point as Default>::default());
}
```